# Input shape in keras (This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output)

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

this is my first time using keras, I'm trying to follow a tutorial I've found online and fit my own data to it. I have a matrix and binary labels.

```
> str(d_train)
 num [1:1062, 1:180] -0.04748 0.04607 -0.05429 -0.0126 -0.00219 ...
> str(trainlabels)
 num [1:1062, 1:2] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
```

my code:

```
model = keras_model_sequential()
model %>%
  layer_dense(units = 8, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(180)) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 3, activation = "softmax")
summary(model)
## Compile
model %>%
  compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy",
          optimizer = "adam",
          metrics = "accuracy")
## Fit model
history = model %>%
  fit(d_train,
      trainlabels,
      epoch=200,
      batch_size=32,
      validation_split=0.2)
```

I can't seem to fit the model, I'm getting this error message:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: A target array with shape (1062, 2) was passed for an output of shape (None, 3) while using as loss `binary_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.
```

Based on the error message, asking for different shape of my input array, I tried to change the dimensions around with no luck.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am not an R expert, but here:

```
layer_dense(units = 3, activation = "softmax")
```

You are telling Keras that the output of your network has three classes. Your labels have shape `(1062, 2)` which suggest it has two classes, hence there is an inconsistency.

You could just change `units = 2` in your last dense and it should work. Also note that you are using the `softmax` activation, and in that case you should prefer to use the `categorical_crossentropy` loss.

To use `binary_crossentropy` for binary classification, you should have `units = 1`, `sigmoid` activation, and labels should be `(1062, 1)` or `(1062,)`, which means they are 0-1 encoded.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I tried following: changed the last layer_dense to 1  used a "sigmoid" activation with binary_crossentropy and instead of one-hot encoding just used a vector of binary encoded values (num [1:1062] 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 ...) and I'm getting another error: Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment

Comment: @MarekPrachař This looks like incompatible versions of tensorflow or keras, you should try the latest for both (tf 1.13 and keras 2.2.4).

Comment: Okay so it seems there was a problem with TensorFlow version 1.13, which can be solved by: install_tensorflow(version = "1.12") After that it's working! Thank you